# Should the data matrix associated with a random vector be transposed?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices, notation, regression

Given a $p$-dimensional zero mean random (column) vector $X \in \mathbb{R}^{p}$, the auto-covariance is given by $$\Sigma = Cov(X) = \mathbb{E}[XX^T].$$
Now given $n$ observations of this column vector, it feels natural to stack each $p$-dimensional observation as new column vectors, i.e. create the data matrix $M \in \mathbb{R}^{p\times n}$, such that the unbiased sample covariance is $\hat{\Sigma} = \tfrac{1}{n-1}MM^T$.

However, in the literature, it is common to arrange variables as columns and observations as rows, i.e. $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$, such that $\hat{\Sigma} = \tfrac{1}{n-1}M^TM$. The benefit of this is that it conforms well with the design matrix used in regression analysis. However, it seems slightly inconsistent with the random vector notation.

While I do understand it is a choice of application, what would you say is the ideal way of arranging the matrix $M$, observations as columns or as rows in order to keep things consistent?

Comment: Suppose $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ are statistically independent observation from a common $p$-dimensional distribution. You can define the sample matrix as $X = [x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ or $Y^\intercal = [x_1, \ldots, x_n].$ The theory arising from $X$ and $Y$ are equivalent and one is obtained from the other by transpose (i.e., any formula would just need transposing). However, the theory from $Y$ is preferred since then the columns of $Y$ are the vectors of observation for each of the $p$ unidimensional features of the distribution. One then writes too $Y = \left[ y_{(1)}, \ldots, y_{(p)} \right].$

Comment: For example, to obtain the vector of means one would usually do $\mathbf{1}^\intercal Y = n \bar y^\intercal$ or $X \mathbf{1} = n \bar{x}.$ Linear regression is written as $y = Y \beta + \varepsilon$ whereas $y^\intercal = \beta^\intercal X + \varepsilon^\intercal.$ And so on...